# First time entry to Schengen area with student visa

Tags: visas, schengen, study

I am currently living outside EU and I recently got a student visa from Germany (multi), but I would like to travel first to Sweden to visit a friend and then flight to Germany. Would that be a problem for extending my student visa, if I don't enter first Germany as a visa issuer?

Comment: @chx A student visa is almost certainly not a Schengen visa.

Comment: Huh? He will be inside Schengen.

Comment: @chx It's a national visa which allows you to travel within the Schengen area.

Comment: @Relaxed Do different regulations apply then? Is it not a duplicate?

Comment: @chx The Schengen regulations apply to short stays (under 90 days) and also grant long-stay visa and residence permit holders some rights with respect to external borders and short stays in other Schengen countries. But the rules and requirements for long stays are still up to each member state and defined almost exclusively through national legislation (*almost* because there are a few EU directives that have an impact on long-stay rules, cf. the EU blue card, freedom of movement, permanent residence and asylum directives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My visa was issued by a German mission abroad. Can I use it to travel to other countries in Europe?

Do I have to enter and leave via Germany or can I do so elsewhere?
**Yes, you can.** Holders of

- a Schengen visa (text on the visa reads "valid for Schengen states")
- a residence permit of a member state or
- a national visa (D-visa)

can stay in the entire Schengen area for up to 90 days in any period of 180 days. The Schengen area consists of the following countries:

Germany, Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden and Switzerland.

The Schengen visa has to be applied for at the foreign mission of the country which is the main destination. The country of entry and departure is not the determining factor. The entry into and departure from the Schengen area can thus occur at any border crossing.

http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/Infoservice/FAQ/VisumFuerD/18-SchengenEinreiseD.html?nn=479790